# Can there be saiyans in other universes differents to universe 6 and universe 7?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

Universe 6 and Universe 7 are twin universes therefore they have the same races, planets, etc. But in Dragon Ball Super episode 96 (spoilers)

> There is a yardrat alien in universe 2, a race of aliens which also exists in universe 7

My question then is, can there be saiyans in other universes different to universe 6 and universe 7?

Comment: Yeah, I don't see why not. I think that Toriyama just hasn't planned that far ahead yet. Manipulating multiverse theory is a lot to take into consideration

Answer (score 2):

Surely I guess there will be saiyans in other universes, but it's just that in the storyline no other universe has that powerful saiyan that can compete in this Tournament. It may be that different universes have different histories of these saiyans.

Comment: As well, saiyans are generally weak. Goku discovered how to get strong, and those around him (Vegeta and the kids) learned from him the secrets. Every other Sayian in universe 7 was weak, with Bardok and King Vegeta were around 10k and were the strongest around. Even Dodoria at around 22k was far stronger than them, and he was one of the weakest Elites in the Freiza army.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so because I remember Wiz-san mentioning that Universe 6 and 7 are parallels that have a lot of similarities, one of which was there being saiyans and having an Earth; albeit the Earth in universe 6 was restored later after having been restored by the super dragon balls. Other universes seem to complement each other in a binary pattern, but I don't believe any more than two universes have commonalities.

Comment: But how do you explain there is a Yardrat (an alien race which exists in universe 6) in universe 2 which isnt a parallel universe to universe 6 or 7? Did he migrate or something?